# Rack servers, N-tier architecture, web app

Tags: web-applications, architecture, rack, n-tier-architecture

I am in the process of building a small scale web application ( max 150,000 concurrent users at any time) but would like the capability to scale up/down should the need arise. In relation to N-tier architecture I have looked at dedicated rack servers for 'Databasing' with use of a RAID PCI express card if possible. I would like to know if I could use the same rack servers for the business logic and client layers too. so in total 3 racks?

Answer (score 0):

Different tiers generally have different constraints on their scalability, and often do better on different hardware.

Database tiers benefit from very fast disk, and lots of memory.

Business logic and UI tiers tend to need more CPU and less need for disk (memory needs vary by application/technology).

All this being said, you can certainly start out with shared servers for all three tiers, and expand as needed later.  You haven't given any indication of architecture/platform/technologies, so giving a recommendation of what hardware you need would be a complete shot in the dark, other than the above general guidelines.

If, for example, your UI tier was a simple HTTP server, serving static content and javascript... then it could absolutely share space with your business layer.

On the other hand, if your UI tier is building lots of dynamic content, you might need to separate it out.

I'd say, build your app, put some load on it using some good load testing tools (there are [many](http://www.appdynamics.com/blog/php/tools-of-the-trade-for-performance-and-load-testing/) out there), and see what is taking up which resources.  This will help you decide what hardware you need to buy.